# Why is this code sending a GET request? Using js.fetch

Tags: javascript, python, rest, fetch-api, pyscript

Code posted below, I had it working earlier but I may have inadvertently changed something and I cannot tell why it's sending a GET request. I'm trying to interact with Flask, for context.

```
txt = "This text here"
data = {"data": txt}

request_params = {
    "method": "PUT",
    "body": data,
    "credentials": "same-origin",
    "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
}
  
resp = await js.fetch(
    '127.0.0.1:5000', 
    to_js(request_params), 
    dict_converter=Object.fromEntries
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not type convert the headers or the body correctly. I think you copied from an example that is wrong.

Change your code to this:

```
from js import fetch, Object
from pyodide.http import to_js

headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

txt = "This text here"
data = {"data": txt}

response = await fetch(
                        '127.0.0.1:5000',
                        method="POST",
                        body=json.dumps(data),
                        headers=Object.fromEntries(to_js(headers))
)
```

Note: I am not sure how to handle this:

```
"credentials": "same-origin",
```